# jqgrid guriddo - edit only one selected column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to edit selected column but not all columns? 
I have 3 columns which have

```
editable: true
```

when I use

```
this.element.jqGrid('editRow',rowId,true);
```

I can edit 3 columns at the same time.
It is great but I need edit only one selected column without trigger remaining two columns.
I tried code from [enter link description here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)
in section "Row Editing (new)" and "Using Events" and work but when I selected cell I have 3 inputs. I need only one on selected column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit only one column just set

```
editable : false
```

to the other two columns and they will be not able to be edit.

If you want to show these columns in the form, but not to edit them you may set a editoptions for the column readonly.

```
{
    name : 'myname', 
    editable: true,...
    editoptions : { readonly: "readonly" ,...}
...
}
```

Also we have a similar [example here](http://guriddo.net/?kbe_knowledgebase=display-hidden-fields-from-grid-in-edit-form-as-texts)